# How to find 3rd max value of a column using MAX function in sql server?

Tags: sql-server-2005, select, max

Yesterday i had a question in an interview which i thought i could find answers here in SO...

How to find 3rd max value of a column using MAX function in sql server?

Consider the column to be

> Wages 
>     20000 
>     15000 
> 10000
>  45000
>  50000

Comment: my 2c: that's a terrible interview question.  code trivia: you'd never actually use that for REAL work!

Comment: *MAYBE* the interviewer was looking for someone who says it would be a very bad practise... (or I could be crediting him/her with too much smarts)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Very UGLY but only using MAX

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        Wages FLOAT
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 20000 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 15000 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 10000
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 45000
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 50000

SELECT  MAX(Wages)
FROM    @Table WHERE Wages < (
                        SELECT  MAX(Wages)
                        FROM    @Table WHERE Wages < (
                                                SELECT  MAX(Wages)
                                                FROM    @Table)
                                )
```

Personally I would have gone with

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
            SELECT  *,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Wages DESC) RowID
            FROM    @Table 
        ) sub
WHERE   RowID = 3
```

And then asked the interviewer why they would ever want a solution using MAX, when they can use built in functionality.

Comment: @astander that worked ... But i wrote the 1st query written by thomas in my interview..

Answer (score 5):

Without using MAX, this is what I can think:

```
SELECT MIN(Wages) FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 3 Wages FROM table ORDER BY Wages DESC;
) As tmp;
```

Select the table by finding the top 3 wages. Then select min from the previous result set.

**UPDATE**: Okay, just read it has to use MAX function. I agree with astander's answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *

FROM table_name temp1

WHERE (n) = (

SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT (temp2.field_name))

FROM table_name temp2

WHERE temp2.field_name > temp1.field_name

)
```

Here n=3 for 3rd max

Answer (score 2):

We can do something like this also, but i really think it is a very bad idea..

```
SELECT TOP 1 col1 
FROM dbo.temp
WHERE col1 NOT IN ( 
            SELECT TOP 2 MAX(col1) 
            FROM dbo.temp
            GROUP BY col1 
            ORDER BY col1 DESC) 
ORDER BY col1 DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct wages 
from @table e1 
where (select count(distinct sal) from @table e2 where e1.wages <= e2.sal)=3;
```

Comment: that does not seem to answer the question, as it does not use the MAX function.

Answer (score 1):

`select wages from table_name order by wages desc limit 2,1`

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Read that I must use the Max function:

```
With RankedWages As
    (
        Select Wage
            , Row_Number() Over( Order By Wage Desc ) As WageRank
        From Wages
    )
Select Wage
From RankedWages As W1
Where WageRank =    (
                    Select Max(W2.WageRank)
                    From RankedWages As W2
                    Where W2.WageRank <= 3
                    )
```

Btw, if the rule was that you *had* to use MAX (meaning anywhere), you could have chea..eh..found a clever workaround by doing:

```
;With RankedWages As
    (
        Select Wage
            , Row_Number() Over( Order By Wage Desc ) As WageRank
        From Wages
    )
Select Max(Wage)
From RankedWages As W1
Where WageRank = 3
```

Comment: @Thomas can i use MAX function?

Comment: How to find 3rd max value of a column using **MAX** function in sql server?

Comment: @astander is it possible to use MAX function?

Comment: As a curiosity, was the interview question that you could *only* use MAX or that you *had* to use MAX?

Comment: @thomas ya.. I wrote your first query but they insisted me to write using MAX

Comment: Gotcha. An intriguing problem with very little use with respect to evaluating a candidate IMO.

Comment: @Pandiya Chendur- IMO stands for "In my opinion".

Answer (score 0):

`select MAX(Salary) from
(
 select top 3 Salary from emp1 order by Salary asc
) as tmp`

Answer (score -1):

```
select min(salary) from (select salary from(select salary from table_name order by salary desc)where rownum<=n);
```

for nth highest salary.

Descrition:

It will first order the salary column in descending order then select first 3 salary,then it will select the minimum salary from selected first 3 salary which is the 3rd highest salary.